# Jest spy on array element

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I store functions in an array. In my tests, I need to spy on the functions in that array. Is this possible?

```
const myArray = [];
myArray.push(() => {
    console.log('first');
});
myArray.push(() => {
    console.log('second');
});
```

For example, how would I spy on the two functions that were added to the array in the code above?

Comment: are the funcs that you are tyring to spy on anonymous ?

Comment: Yes, they are. I was thinking of spying on the via their index in the array, but that did not seem to work.

Comment: Please, explain your case further. *that did not seem to work* - what exactly did you try?

Comment: You can't spy on a standalone function.